# pip install planemo fails with error: "ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/locale'"

Tags: python, installation, pip, permissions, bioinformatics

I am trying to install [`planemo`](https://planemo.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/stable/pdf/) like so:

```bash
/usr/local/bin/pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv .venv
. .venv/bin/activate
/usr/local/bin/pip3 install planemo
```

The last command fails with this error message:

```bash
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/locale'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

WARNING: You are using pip version 21.0.1; however, version 22.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
. .venv/bin/activate
```

This line activates your virtual environment. "activating" in this case means setting a bunch of environment variables, including `PATH`.

```
/usr/local/bin/pip3 install planemo
```

And then you completely ignore `PATH` by calling pip3 with an absolute path. Make that

```
pip install planemo
```

and it should work.

Comment: This is the preferred solution, as it installs `planemo` inside the virtualenv. To access it later: `source ~/.venv/bin/activate`. Then `which planemo` should give you something like this: `/path/to/.venv/bin/planemo`. To leave virtualenv: `deactivate`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem is just that the library exists in site-packages and was likely installed using sudo (accidentally or otherwise), just cd into site-packages, check permissions `ls -all` and if the package is 'root' then remove it and reinstall it

Answer (score -1):

**DO NOT USE: this solution does install `planemo`, but into an *incorrect* location.**

The error is caused by an outdated version of `pip`. Note that the error message is followed by a few hints, one of which solves the issue. Just upgrade `pip`:

```bash
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Now this works:

```bash
/usr/local/bin/pip3 install planemo
```

```bash
which planemo
# /usr/local/bin/planemo
```

Comment: Why would upgrading pip fix the fact that the user doesn't have write permissions to the global python installation?

Comment: @Sören: I agree that this is really odd. But it did work, in the sense that it did not generate any more errors, and resulted in a functional `planemo` installation. This is part of the reason why I posted my solution.

Comment: Where was planemo installed to? Inside or outside the virtualenv?

Comment: @Sören: `which planemo
/usr/local/bin/planemo`

Comment: So, outside the virtualenv, somewhere a normal user shouldn't have write permissions. Whatever you did, I wouldn't consider this a working solution.